# Are there approximation formulae for the Jacobi Theta Functions?

Tags: math, formula, mathematical-expressions, polynomial-approximations, function-approximation

I am looking for **a complex-number approximation formula for the [Jacobi Theta Functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) that only uses simple functions**. By simple, I mean supported natively by most programming languages and does not involve too many [special functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions) as prerequisites like what C++ has, thus I may implement the formula using different languages.

I have searched on the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.14) and the [Wolfram Functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta1/introductions/JacobiThetas/), but still do not find anything other than infinite series or products.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: There's some C++ implementations here: <https://github.com/stla/jacobi/tree/main/src>